# Unable to call .net method From java using jna?

Tags: java, jna

i tried to  make java application that was in c , the link for source is http://phtranslator.sourceforge.net/ i did the following things to call that coe but make it

```
public class Main {

/** Creates a new instance of Main */
public Main() {
}
public interface simpleDLL extends Library {
    simpleDLL INSTANCE = (simpleDLL) Native.loadLibrary(
        (Platform.isWindows() ? "C:\\translator\\PhTranslateLib.dll" : "simpleDLLLinuxPort"), simpleDLL.class);

    public   IntByReference  GetTeluguTranslator();
    public  int Translate(IntByReference Translator, String szInput,  StringBuilder szOutput, int nLen);
    public   int GetTranslatedBufferLength(IntByReference Translator,  String szInput, Pointer out);
    public  void  GetTranslatedBuffer(String szOutput, Pointer ppHint);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{     

    StringBuilder b =new StringBuilder();
      simpleDLL sdll = simpleDLL.INSTANCE;
      IntByReference  y = sdll.GetTeluguTranslator();
    int j=  sdll.Translate( y , "ananathapura", b, 0);

    System.out.println( b);

    System.out.println(j);




}
```

}

```
I am getting Following `Exception` 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported argument type java.lang.StringBuilder at parameter 2 of function Translate
    at com.sun.jna.Function.convertArgument(Function.java:552)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:258)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:216)
    at $Proxy0.Translate(Unknown Source)
    at anil.test.Main.main(Main.java:71)
```

is a replace `String builder` with string i got success , but out not stored in `string`

Comment: what ever it be ,no problem even your name  it must converted in to telugu ,i got length of that buffer  when working with string but unable to get that string

Comment: Seems like String has to be passed rather than "StringBuffer" in Translate function. did you try with "String"

Comment: Are you sure that  `Translate` taking String ?

Comment: c version of that have data type as wchar_t* so in java i  it will be character equivalent i tried that also but no gain(i changed both abstract and concrete declaration)

Comment: I saw some line in that tutorial that,Passing `null` instead of `b`,have you tried like that ??

Comment: but where to get my output buffer

Comment: Why not try passing it a pre-allocated `char[]`?

Comment: i tried with Character[] i got Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported array argument type: class java.lang.Character

Answer (score 1):

The `Translate` method accepts the return buffer and also its capacity (nlen) so that no more than nlen characters will be stored in it (to ensure protection against string overflow).

So, in your case you want to ensure,

1. A string buffer is allocated with enough memory before the `Translate` call
2. You specify the correct size of the buffer in the call - so that the buffer will be filled upto that length

For example, as per your code you should be doing something like

```
 // fill no more than 19 chars (+1 char for \0) in b
 int j=  sdll.Translate( y , "ananathapura", b, 20);
```

Here 20 is a rough guess. Make sure your string `b` is capable of holding 20 wide-characters if you specify 20 (I hope java has some way of pre-allocating string space). Since in your code you specified 0 for the nLen, it did not store anything.

Now, in production you may want to allocate a string that is large enough to hold all the converted unicode characters (and not hard-code it as 20).

But, how would you know how large the converted string is going to be? It is not like one English character will be translated exactly to one Telugu or Hindi character.

This is where the `GetTranslatedBufferLength` and related routines come into picture.

Refer to inline [code comments](https://sourceforge.net/p/phtranslator/code/45/tree/PhTranslateLib/PhTranslateLib.cpp#l57) and the [documentation](http://phtranslator.sourceforge.net/#_Toc227603221) for further details on that concept.

Hope this helps.

Comment: all the problem with using string now just placed char[] it works fine thank